# In Powershell, how do I print out the data from a custom folder of Outlook(within Inbox)?

Tags: powershell

I want to run a Powershell script against a custom folder within my Outlook inbox:

[image]
This is the query I have so far :

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application

$outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent._Folders("UFMS").Items
```

but this is giving me the error :

```
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:48
+ $newFolder = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder( <<<< olFolderCalendar).Parent._Folders("UFMS").Items
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's what I do. It may be a little clumsy, but it works.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$MyAcct = $Namespace.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match $env:USERNAME}
$Inbox = $MyAcct.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match "Inbox"}
$UFMS = $Inbox.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match "UFMS"}
```

That opens Outlook, gets the MAPI namespace, finds your account (based off your UserID, so this assumes your AD Account Name is in your email address), then it looks in the folders for Inbox, and then looks in your Inbox folders for one named UFMS. Then you can iterate through the mail in that folder with `$UFMS.Items`.

**Bonus:** It's good to remember that Outlook lists the oldest email item as item 1, and provides them in an oldest-to-newest style. To just get the email from today you can use a For loop, going from the last item in the collection to the first, and break out when the current item is too old. Like this:

```
[datetime]$StartDate = ([datetime]::now.ToShortDateString())
$TodaysMail = @()
for($i= ($UFMS.Items.count - 1);$i -ge 0;$i--){
    $Current = $UFMS.Items.item($i)
    if($Current.senton -lt (get-date $StartDate)){break}
    $TodaysMail+=$Current
}
```

The `$StartDate=` line may look overly complicated, but that gets you a [DateTime] object equal to midnight of the current day.

Comment: I think so, I would just do it a little differently than you. Rather than process each email, use Where to only select the ones you want, then you can either work with the mail items, or you can run a ForEach loop to return the matching numbers. `$UFMS.Items | Where{$_.Subject -match "(\d{6})"} | ForEach{$Matches[1]}` That would spit back all of the 6 digit numbers found in the subjects of the emails in that folder.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer fulfills your needs please mark it as accepted so that future users can utilize it if they have a similar issue, and so that other answer givers don't spend time trying to answer it if no other answer is needed.

Comment: hmmm , not sure why but `$UFMS.Items | Where{$_.Subject -match "(\d{6})"} | ForEach{$Matches[1]}` returns nothing yet

Comment: Hi  , I have a new question about PS . Maybe you might be able to help ? thanks !!! link   -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971705/in-powershell-how-do-i-print-out-only-the-data-from-todayor-a-specific-date-ra

Comment: Revisiting this one again. So the 2nd block of code you show will start with the most recent emails (which is given by `$UFMS.Items.count - 1` )  . IE the newest email is obtained by getting the highest count ?

Comment: Other question  : after the 2nd block of code runs , then the array `$TodaysMail` will have all the numbers in it . But this code by itself doesnt print out those # 's

Comment: @TheTechnician , got it figured, nevermin !!